# Javascript - Mobile Swipe Scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-7, scroll, touch

I am trying to implement some type of touch based scrolling with Javascript. I have found a few options, [this](http://james.lin.net.nz/2010/09/27/javascript-swipe-demo-works-both-with-finger-ipad-and-mouse-pc/) and [this](http://touchswipedemo.celestialcitizen.jit.su/), but neither work on Windows Phone 7 devices. My website is primarily for my Windows Phone apps, so they will not work. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Check out jQuery's Mobile UI. It has been built specifically for mobile devices. Plus you can also use it as a wrapper to present you content in a mobile friendly way.

http://jquerymobile.com/